# How to delete downloaded apk file right after it install to phone

Tags: android

I'v already read post about:

```
BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // do whatever you want to do
    }
};

registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("ACTION"));
unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
```

Intents:

```
ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL
ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED
ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED
ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED
```

How to do subject or when installation failed

Comment: what i understand is that you want to know if APK installation is failed.  If i understand it correctly , you will not be able getting broadcast for ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED ,ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED ,ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED if installation fails. All the intents will not help you to identify failed installation.

Comment: This actions contains Extra RESULT_OK and RESULT_FIRST_USER but I don't know how to use It/ May you know how?